# Graph and save serial data into processing

Tags: arduino, serial-port, processing, graphing

Just wanted to say I've been using the forums to learn a lot so thank you to all contributors and supporters of stack overflow.

I'm a student new to processing/arduino and I'm trying to make a processing sketch that takes serial data and graphs multiple sensor values on different graphs, while having the ability for the user to record all data into a CSV. Also I was wondering how to make a simple text box that updated and printed one of the sensor values.

A very basic snippet of my arduino serial printout code includes:

```
Serial.print(sensor1);
Serial.print(",");
Serial.print(sensor2);
Serial.print(",");
Serial.print(sensor3);
Serial.println(",");

//Sensor1 and 2, would be on separate graphs, and 3 would be a single printed value updated frequently.
```

For processing I've seen very basic examples and was wondering if what would be easier/better: to do a direct graph using the map function or to setup a cgraph and cdata arrays (saw in another example). Lastly while using a create writer or filewriter for saving data, is there a way to have new files being created rather than overwriting or appending data? Could I use an if statement to get user input text to type in the filename to avoid an overwrite?

I would be greatful for any hints or help.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably send a new line character at the end:

```
Serial.print(sensor1);
Serial.print(",");
Serial.print(sensor2);
Serial.print(",");
Serial.print(sensor3);
Serial.println();
```

Once that's done you can use Serial's [bufferUntil()](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_bufferUntil_.html) to keep track of each line for you. Then in [serialEvent()](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/serialEvent_.html) you can simply [readString()](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_readString_.html)
In terms of saving to a CSV file, you can append each line to an [ArrayList](https://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html).
(Alternatively you can used a typical `String[]` but you have to manually manage the line index and [expand()](https://processing.org/reference/expand_.html) the array when new lines come in. ArrayList may be simpler). Whenever you want to save the CSV file, you can easily convert the ArrayList to a String[] which is what [saveStrings()](https://processing.org/reference/saveStrings_.html) expects. In terms of saving new files, you can simply create a timestamp string:

```
import processing.serial.*;
//serial port
Serial arduino;
//timestamp used for CSV filename
String timestamp;
//current CSV line received from Arduino
String currentLine = "";
//all lines received from Arduino
ArrayList<String> csvData = new ArrayList<String>();


void setup(){
  try{
    //be sure use the correct port/baud rate
    arduino = new Serial(this,"/SERIAL_PORT_HERE",115200);
    arduino.bufferUntil('\n');
  }catch(Exception e){
    System.err.println("Error initializing serial port!\nPlease check the PORT NAME, BAUD RATE and USB connections\nAlso close Serial Monitor or other serial port connections (if any)");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
void draw(){
  background(0);
  text(currentLine,10,15);
}
void serialEvent(Serial s){
  //read data from serial port
  currentLine = s.readString();
  //append data to be later saved as a CSV file
  csvData.add(currentLine);
  //process current values - update plot, not fully implemented
  processCurrentLine();
}
void processCurrentLine(){
  //parse and update plot here
  try{
    String[] values = currentLine.split(",");
    printArray(values);
  }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
void saveCSV(){
  //create a timestamp to be used for the CSV filename (avoiding the file being overwritten 
  timestamp = day()+"-"+month()+"-"+year()+" "+hour()+":"+minute()+":"+second();
  println("saving CSV file");
  saveStrings(timestamp+".csv",csvData.toArray(new String[csvData.size()]));
}
//save on 's' key 
void keyReleased(){
  if(key == 's') saveCSV();
}
//save on exit
void exit(){
  saveCSV();
  super.exit();
}
```

If you're on Windows, you might want to checkout [SerialChart](https://code.google.com/p/serialchart/).
It's a nice simple Qt based UI for rendering graphcs based on CSV formatted Serial data. It should also allow you to save the data and it provides a few configuration settings too.

[image: Serial Chart preview]

**Update**
I have recently noticed Arduino 1.6.6 (or newer) has a [built in Serial Plotter](http://makezine.com/2015/11/04/arduino-ide-software-update/)

[image: Arduino integrated Serial Plotter]